# Trouble with resetting passwords

Tags: password, forgot-password

On a site running EE 2.7.2 there is a problem with resetting passwords from the auto-generated reset link.

When a user clicks on **Forgot your password?** at the login screen and submits their email address, an email with the following link is generated:

> http://sitexyz.com/index.php?S=0&D=cp&C=login&M=reset_password&resetcode=KJ82wnTS

However, when you click on that link it takes you to the home page instead of the password reset page. Any clues why this is happening and what the solution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the CP Url in the config file. It had the CP as index.php instead of admin.php.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The CP URL in the config file was already set as admin.php for myself.

I am still running into the issue that the link sends you back to the home page. The link is correct...  ".com/preferred-member-registration/forgot_password", however this 'forgot password' URL is linked to the sites homepage.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you are clicking on a link and it takes you to the home page instead of the intended page, I would double check the URL to make sure it actually corresponds to an actual page.